# How do I find the range of $y=\log(2x^5-3x^2+2)$?

Tags: calculus

Range of
$y=\log(2x^5-3x^2+2)$
I'm in high school, I just want to know the most effective method of solving questions like these.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Start from the inside.  What is the range of the polynomial?  You restrict that to the domain of $\log$.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @RossMillikan.  At the same time, **if** it is not too much of a stretch, stretch your intuition to ask yourself (for example), what values of $(a)$ lead to what values of $\log(a)$.  You know that $\log(a)$ is undefined if $a \leq 0$.  You also know that as $a$ approaches $(0)$ **from above**, that $\log(a)$ is going to $-\infty$.  You also know that as $a$ approaches $(1)$ from either above or below, that $\log(a)$ is going to $(0)$.  Finally, you know that as $a$ goes to $+\infty, ~\log(a)$ also goes to $+\infty.$

Comment: thanks guys, i also just realised that the range of an odd degree polynomial is all real numbers, so that means all positive values can be inputted in the logarithm. And hence the range of the function is going to be all real numbers.

Comment: Your reasoning in that last comment is absolutely correct!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific function, I believe the range is $\mathbb R$.

Generally, you should look at each of the more complicated parts of the function, and look at how they might only output a certain range of numbers, e.g. $x^2\ge0$ and $-1\le sin(x)\le1$ regardless of what $x$ is. Then, think about how that might constrain the output of the function as a whole. Also consider that the range can only include values that can be reached from the domain. $f(x)=\frac{x^2+x}{x}$ might seem like it has a range of $\mathbb R$, but the domain is $x\neq0$, therefore the range is $x\neq1$.

Comment: A lot of students may not know what $\sin(x)$ means at this level.

Comment: Yeah thanks, got it!